# Putting a UIPageControl on top of a UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, paging, uipagecontrol

I've got a UIScrollView displaying three images, (currently two UIImages and a UIColor as I haven't received the third graphic yet) and I've been trying to add a UIPageControl but having a few problems.

I need the UIPageControl to have a transparent background (which is easy enough in IB) and then for it to sit on top of the UIScrollView and display which page the user is on.

First problem is that the UIPageControl is behind the UIScrollView.
Second problem is that it scrolls away with the first page when you try and go onto the second (if I text out the image and it is visible behind it).
Third problem is that I believe it doesn't show which page the user is on (although it might work and me just not be able to see because of the second problem!)

I'm fairly new to XCode but have been using it for a couple weeks so I'm not a complete amateur. I've been looking for a fix for this for a while now and can't seem to find anything else on it. Sorry if this question has come up before and me just not find it!

Here is my Code:

HomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIPageControl *pageControl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage       imageNamed:@"SuperflyPoster_1.jpg"]], [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SuperflyPoster_2.jpg"]], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width *i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    [subview release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width *colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
// Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}  


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
self.scrollView = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
[pageControl release];
[scrollView release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- problem 1: if you are using storyboard to layout your views, that is because you put scrollview before your pagecontrol view, if you are using addSubview to add , that is because you add pagecontrol first , scrollview second.
- problem 1 solution: put scrollview to be the first, pagecontrolview to be the second.
- problem 2: that is because your pagecontrolview is the subview of scrollview, that is wrong, scrollview and pagecrontrolview should be in the same layer.
- problem 2 solution: just make them on the same layer.
- problem 3 , you can see my code.

Sincerely, the problems you meet with are all the problems I have met with , too. So, I have written a PagedImageScrollView to make it simple and maybe you can also learn from it , here is the link

---

[PagedImageScrollView](https://github.com/jianpx/ios-cabin/tree/master/PagedImageScrollView)

---

Hopes to help. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is fairly old, and since I've searched here for help and solved the problem myself afterwards, I think a answer might help others.

Problem 1 & 2: The reason for your first and second problem is because when you drag a UIPageControl into the storyboard, you probably put it on your scrollview, which makes it a subview of the scrollview. And after you add Image or other contents to the scroll view, the new contents will cover the UIPageControl, and since pageControl is a subview of the scrollview, it will scroll with the contents, and scroll off screen.

Solve 1 & 2: You should put the UIPageControl and ScrollView in the same level as subviews to the base View of the Controller, and the UIPageControl should appear below the UIScrollview in 'Document Outline' (lower in document outline means in the front in view). To do this, you might want to drag in the UIPageControl first, and then drag in the scrollview, resize the scrollview, and then switch their positions in the 'Document outline'.

Problem 3: It seems that you set your pageControl's page properly, if you can see your pagecontrol, it might already working. And you should set the scrollView's enable paging to YES.